# Changing the previous NODE value based on current node value in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am Struggling with the below issue.
Hope any one of you suggest or guide me to resolve this .

I have a payload of below pseudo xsd type.

```
<element name=Main maxCoccurs=unbounded>
        <complexType>
            <element name=input1/>
            <element name=input2/>
            <element name=input3/>
            <element name=input4/>
            <element name=input5/>
            <element name=inside/>
                <element name=username/>
                <element name=address/>
        </complextype>
    <element>
```

Main is a repeatable element.
I want to check for username, if the value in username of all the nodes are not equal, then I need to assign blank value to the first node username.

How can I do this in transformation?

I am trying this as below:
get the firt username in a  variable, and then check that with all the usernames using for-each.
if its not equal.... But I cant assign the blank value to the first node, as I am some where in username of nth node.

I was thinking of using a variable to say unmatched=true(), but xslt cant allow us to make the change to the variable once declared.
So even that option is ruled out.

How can I achieve this??
Help me to resolve this..

Hope I am clear.

Cheers
Chandru

Comment: Using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Comment: You've tagged this as both xslt 1.0 and 2.0 - which one do you actually want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `foo` is the name of the parent element of the `main` elements you could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo[some $m in main satisfies $m/username != main/username]/main[1]/username">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is some input sample:

```
<root>
  <foo>
     <main>
       <input1/>
       <input2/>
       <input3/>
       <input4/>
       <input5/>
       <inside/>
       <username>u1</username>
       <address/>
     </main>
     <main>
       <input1/>
       <input2/>
       <input3/>
       <input4/>
       <input5/>
       <inside/>
       <username>u1</username>
       <address/>
     </main>
     <main>
       <input1/>
       <input2/>
       <input3/>
       <input4/>
       <input5/>
       <inside/>
       <username>u2</username>
       <address/>
     </main>
     <main>
       <input1/>
       <input2/>
       <input3/>
       <input4/>
       <input5/>
       <inside/>
       <username>u1</username>
       <address/>
     </main>
  </foo>
</root>
```

When the stylesheet is applied with Saxon 9.4, the output I get is

```
<root>
  <foo>
     <main>
       <input1/>
       <input2/>
       <input3/>
       <input4/>
       <input5/>
       <inside/>
       <username/>
       <address/>
     </main>
     <main>
       <input1/>
       <input2/>
       <input3/>
       <input4/>
       <input5/>
       <inside/>
       <username>u1</username>
       <address/>
     </main>
     <main>
       <input1/>
       <input2/>
       <input3/>
       <input4/>
       <input5/>
       <inside/>
       <username>u2</username>
       <address/>
     </main>
     <main>
       <input1/>
       <input2/>
       <input3/>
       <input4/>
       <input5/>
       <inside/>
       <username>u1</username>
       <address/>
     </main>
  </foo>
</root>
```

where the `username` of the first `main` is empty now because there is one `main` with a `username` that is different from the other ones.

[edit]
I am slightly confused as the answer is accepted, yet a comment says you need an XSLT 1.0 solution. I will provide an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo[main[username != ../main/username]]/main[1]/username">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. I removed xslt 1.0 tag now. @Martin, I find it is little difficult to understand your solution. Is it fine with you to eloberate it little more.

Comment: You said "I want to check for username, if the value in username of all the nodes are not equal, then I need to assign blank value to the first node username". For me with XSLT 2.0 that "translates" into writing a template for the `username` child of the first `main`  (`main[1]`) element if the condition is met. But I think I wrote the wrong predicate check with `not( = )`. I will edit and provide a tested code sample.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin... I apologise as the xslt version is 1.0 and not 2.0. I tried the solution you have provided to me, but unfortunately it didnt work for me.. :(